# I have included the images of error i am encountering

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Write a Python program that displays a message as follows for a given number:

If it is a multiple of three, display "Zip" If it is a multiple of five, display "Zap". If it is a multiple of both three and five, display "Zoom". If it does not satisfy any of the above given conditions, display "Invalid".
    #PF-Exer-11

```
def display(num):
    message=""
    #write your logic here
    if(num%3==0):
        print("zip")
    elif(num%5==0):
        print("zap")
    elif(num%3==0 and num%5==0):
        print("zoom")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
    return message


[enter image description here][1]
#Provide different values for num and test your program
message=display(9)
print(message)[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow !
Please, when you post a question make sure to explicitly state what the problem you encounter and how to reproduce it to make it easier for helpers to answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually specify what your issue is but I'm taking a wild guess that an input of 15 prints `zip` and not `zoom`...

Move the check for being a multiple of 3 and 5 first.

```py
def display(num):
    message=""
    #write your logic here
    if(num%3==0 and num%5==0): # <<<< this first
        print("zoom")
    elif(num%3==0):
        print("zip")
    elif(num%5==0):
        print("zap")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
    return message
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the simplest solution I can think of :)

```
def display(num):
    #write your logic here
    if(num%3==0 and num%5==0):
        return "Zoom"
    elif(num%5==0):
        return "Zap"
    elif(num%3==0):
        return "Zip"
    else:
        return "Invalid"

print(display(15))
```